# Explode Structs in Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, struct, pyspark

Source Struct:

```
 root
 |-- return: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- traces: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- site_details: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- latitude: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- longitude: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- org_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- short_name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- timezone: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- trace: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- q: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- t: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- v: string (nullable = true)
```

when I explode site details as

```
dataresponse.select("return.traces.site_details").select(F.explode('site_details').alias('data')).select('data.*')
```

its all good and the result is as below:

[image]

but with traces: when i do

```
dataresponse.select(F.explode("return.traces.trace").alias('data')).select('data.q', 'data.t', 'data.v')
```

Returns:

```
x:pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame
q:array
   element:long
t:array
   element:long
v:array
   element:string
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|                   q|                   t|                   v|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9...|[19730101010000, ...|[1.2316, 1.2316, ...|
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Then am trying to explode array columns as below:

```
x.withColumn("t", explode("t")).withColumn("q", explode("q")).withColumn("v", explode("v"))
```

this is taking very long...
is there better way to do this ???

Comment: explode is an expensive operation in terms of memory and processing time so it makes sense, could you give sample data and corresponding expected output  >

Comment: If you would have checked your code on a small data sample, you would have seen that your are creating a cartesian product between q, t & v.
It seems what you really want to do is to zip the elements of q,t & v and only then explode it

Comment: @AnandVidvat why would you assume "explode is an expensive operation in terms of memory"? All you need to do it to iterate through the collection and output a record for each element you encounter during the process.

Comment: The explode() of even a small array could lead to a spill if the worker nodes don't have enough memory

Answer (score -1):

Ended up create list for each row and then pandas df from the the lists

```
tracedf = dataresponse.select(F.explode("return.traces.trace").alias('data')).select('data.q', 'data.t', 'data.v')

q = tracedf.collect()[0]['q']
t = tracedf.collect()[0]['t']
v = tracedf.collect()[0]['v']

dataPdbyYear = pd.DataFrame({"q" : q, "t" : t, "v" : v})
```

Comment: The original code was erroneous so there is no need for a workaround.
In addition, pandas is not scalable.